# Windows Server 2012 WDS and Linux Booting

Tags: linux, windows, windows-server-2012, wds

I've been playing with WDS for awhile now because I want to setup a network based boot system for all my business to make it quicker to load images. We use a lot of Linux based OSes and after some searching there is no mention in the documentation about Linux support.

Does WDS support Linux PXE booting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you tried to look for the documentation online about WDS and Linux, but once I Googled that I found a lot of articles that talks exactly about this topic, I liked those links:

- [Deep Dive: Combining Windows Deployment Services & PXELinux for the ultimate network boot](http://thommck.wordpress.com/2011/09/09/deep-dive-combining-windows-deployment-services-pxelinux-for-the-ultimate-network-boot/)
- [Creating a PXE Boot menu for deploying Linux with Windows Deployment Services (WDS)](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/WDSLINUX)