# Capture Linux OS image using in-built application?

Tags: linux, wds, image, sysprep

I have an issue.

I want to know if I can capture any Linux OS custom image using an in-built app?
Example -  I can use SysPrep to capture Windows image, but how do I go about capturing Linux image?

Because after capturing, I want to use WDS (Windows Deployment Service) through Server 2008 R2 to deploy the windows and Linux images on new systems. I don't want to use any third party applications to capture the Linux image as it is a requirement.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You can't "capture the Linux image" because [WDS doesn't support this](http://windowsitpro.com/system-center-2012/q-can-i-deploy-linux-windows-deployment-services-and-other-microsoft-technologies). But you can [PXE boot a Linux installation](http://serverfault.com/q/546961/126632) which you can then automate with Linux-native tools.

Comment: You haven't mentioned which Linux distribution you're interested in, so no one knows what tools might be available in your distribution of choice. It's also not clear what you mean by "third party". In general, your requirements need to be more clearly specified.

Answer (score -2):

Google dd but make sure that no write processes are running on the machine while the Backup is running

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, as it won't create something that can be handled by WDS ...